# Help solving this optimisation problem (maximisation of objective function with leontief as constraint)

Tags: optimization, problem-solving, math-software

Would you like to help me solve this optimisation problem?

### $$
\max_{Y_j,A_j,B_j}\pi_j = p_j Y_j - (p_a A_j + p_bB_j)\\
\text{subject to } Y_j = \min\left(\frac{A_j}{\alpha_a}; \frac{B_j}{\beta_b} \right)
$$

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzJJ5.png)

As you can see above, I'm trying to maximise Y, but the tricky bit is that the constraint is a Leontief function.

In this example, I'm supposed to find the optimal quantities of A_j and B_j as inputs to maximise the quantity of the output Y_j, . alpha and beta are the coefficients of the leontief function.

As much as I'd like an answer, I hope you can teach me the trick to find the solution, not just give a direct solution. Thank you so much

Does anyone know how to do symbolic solving of optimisation problems on maple? I have it but I don't know how to use it for optimisation problems specifically.

Comment: Please try to write using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  or latex.

Comment: Your notation is unclear. Please clarify whether each quantity is supposed to be a scalar or a matrix. Is there a meaning to the subscript $j$? Are the $A$ and $B$ in the constraint supposed to be $A_j$ and $B_j$? If not, is there some implicit relationship here between $A$ and $A_j$?

Comment: Thank you, and I apologise for the mistakes. I have corrected them. Thank you for correcting my question too. (My English is horrible, relatively to yours)

Comment: No help available?